# ¿Cómo insertar datos al segundo intento?

Tags: php, mysqli

Cómo puedo insertar los datos al segundo intento de dar clic en iniciar sesión de igual forma insertar los datos pero solo redireccionar al segundo intento.

```
$msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['new_account'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $msg = "Por favor, ingresé su usuario";
    }

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO data_users (email, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username,$password);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        header('location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Formulario

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="#">
    <input name="username" type="email" value="" placeholder="alguien@example.com" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Contrase&#241;a" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesi&#243;n" name="new_account">
</form>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿A qué te refieres con *dar click*, y con *segundo intento*?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias por la bienvenida :), dar clic en el botón registrar, pero no redireccionar el primer intento de registro sino en el segundo, estoy en mi clase hackin ethico, necesito entregar mi proyecto.

Comment: @A.Cedano He agregado el formulario

Comment: Bien bien, ahora se entiende mejor. Pero, ¿hay un motivo justificado para ese comportamiento (requerimiento del proyecto), o es para manejar una situación incómoda del código y piensas (erróneamente) que esa es la mejor salida? Pregunto porque es raro que quieras obligar al usuario a repetir una acción.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si es necesario obligar que el usuario repita la acción, porque necesito darle un justificativo, por decir aveces el usuario desconfiado registra datos erroneo entonces la idea es justificar mi tarea, por medio de un segundo intento decirle que el usuario y contraseña es incorrecto y, hacerle repetir la acción, pero ambos intentos igual forma debe registrase los datos.

Comment: Ummm lo mejor que se me ocurre es un contador de clicks, pero en el botón HTML. Y usar Ajax también para enviar el formulario. No sé si está permitido en tu proyecto y si lo estás implementando.

Comment: @A.Cedano En realidad no estoy implementado Ajax pero si no es mucho pedir puedes darme un ejemplo usando ajax y poder guiarme en lo que estoy haciendo ahora solo en php -> https://ideone.com/TmqIfV también, ya luego ver cual me conviene usar

Comment: Es que ese no es un problema para resolverlo en PHP, sino en Javascript. Cuando el formulario se envía hay recursos que se consumen (de servidor, de red...), por lo tanto, si se requiere procesar los datos PHP solamente al segundo click, tienes que poner un contador de clicks en el HTML y lanzar la petición al servidor solamente en el segundo click (no es correcto mandar datos al servidor sin sentido en un 1er click). Si quieres te puedo poner un ejemplo de eso, usando Ajax/jQuery. Es otro concepto totalmente distinto, pero mucho mejor.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si por favor muéstrame el ejemplo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería una forma de controlar los clicks del botón.

He cambiando el elemento, en vez de `input` a `button`, porque así podemos usar el `value` para actualizar la cantidad de clicks que se hacen en él.

En el código Javascript se escuchan los clicks del botón, se aumente el valor en `1` cada vez y cuando sean dos se imprime un mensaje. En ese bloque lanzarías tu petición Ajax, que llamaría al archivo PHP que procesa los datos.

OJO: Ajax es algo mucho mejor y más avanzado. Si quieres, podrías evitar incluso la redirección, actualizando la misma página del formulario. Pero, dado que es un proyecto, no sé cuáles son las limitaciones, ni qué se puede hacer o no hacer.

Otro vacío que no queda claro en tu pregunta es: *¿qué pasa al tercer click, al cuarto, al quinto?* Ese tipo de situaciones hay que cubrirlos. Se podría por ejemplo desactivar el botón desde el bloque del segundo click o algo así. Todo depende de la lógica de tu programa. Lo señalo aquí para que lo tengas en cuenta...

Espero te sirva. Si necesitas ayuda con Ajax (para mandar a ejecutar el código de PHP) lo dices y te pongo un ejemplo.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnSession").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value++;
    console.log(`Haz hecho click ${this.value} veces`);
    if (this.value == 2) {
      console.log('Aquí llamamos al servidor');
    } else {
      console.log('Aquí hacemos otra cosa');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="#">
  <input name="username" type="email" value="" placeholder="alguien@example.com" autocomplete="off" />
  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Contrase&#241;a" autocomplete="off" />
  <button id="btnSession" type="submit" value="0" name="new_account">Iniciar sesi&#243;n</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 0):

Si tu rutina de inserción en la base de datos y el formulario se encuentran en el mismo script, se podría resolver con PHP puro de la siguiente forma.

```
<?php

function insertar_db() {
    echo 'Insertando valores en la base de datos';
    // [ Rutina de insertar en la base de datos ]
}

function mostrar_formulario() {
    $contador = isset($_POST['cont']) ? intval($_POST['cont']) : 0;
    ?>
    <form method="post" autocomplete="off" action="">
        <input name="cont" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ++$contador; ?>" >
        <input name="username" type="email" value="" placeholder="alguien@example.com" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Contrase&#241;a" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesi&#243;n" name="new_account">
    </form>
    <?php
}

if(!isset($_POST['cont']) or ($_POST['cont'] <= 1)) {
    mostrar_formulario();
} else {
    insertar_db();
}
```

Si el script que inserta en la DB está en otro archivo, entonces tendrás que usar JS o herramientas similares.